# How to enable secure cookie to the application which is running using Load Balancer?

Tags: ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, load-balancing

Our production environment configured in N number of pods with load balancer?

Our website is only accessible using VPN.

When we enable secure cookie in application level, it does not work as expected.

Need to enabled secure flag on the application which has been hosted in **kubernetes(EKS)** cluster and exposed through **Loadbalancer -> Ingress -> service** , we need to enable secure flag and how it can be configured, do we need to offload SSL on the app level or any other way that can configure?

Note:
SSL is enabled only in Load balancer. Internally(Instances) the request are http only.